# Entity System.NotSupportedException when querying with FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to retrieve a unique element if it exist, or null if it doesn't.

my function is :

```
private Dealer GetOrCreateDealer(DataRow dataRow)
{
        ModelCamwareContext localContext = new ModelCamwareContext();
        string test = dataRow["Dealer"].ToString();
        Dealer dealer = localContext.Dealers.Where(x => x.Name == dataRow["Dealer"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        if (dealer != null)
        {
         ...
        }
        else
        {
         ...
        }
}
```

my test string is just here to make sure I had no problem with the dataRow info, it works as expected and gives me the string on which I want to select my dealer.

Unless I am mistaken, FirstOrDefault should not give me any exception in case there is no dealer to retrieve, I should in that case have dealer = null.

The exception I get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: You should check the full exception message. Most likely the not supported exception is caused by `x => x.Name == dataRow["Dealer"].ToString()` expression. Replace it with `x => x.Name == test)`

Comment: You're right, the problem came from there.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity cannot evaluate datatables values inside it's LINQ. Try something like this:

```
    ModelCamwareContext localContext = new ModelCamwareContext();
    string test = dataRow["Dealer"].ToString();
    Dealer dealer = localContext.Dealers.Where(x => x.Name == test).FirstOrDefault();
    if (dealer != null)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```